# Matlab least square nonlinear optimization

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I am trying to run a system identification problem, my objective is to identify three (finite element) parameters, such that the analysis will make predictions as close to measured ones. Basically a least square nonlinear problem with Matlab's function nonlin. I keep on getting:

```
Initial point is a local minimum.

Optimization completed because the size of the gradient at the initial point 
is less than the value of the optimality tolerance.
Optimization completed: The final point is the initial point.
The first-order optimality measure, 0.000000e+00, is less than
options.OptimalityTolerance = 1.000000e-10.
```

My options are

```
maxfuneval=1.4e7;
maxiter=1e5;
tolfun=1e-10;
tolx=1e-14;
maxPCGiter=40;
tolPCG=1e-14;
TypicalX=[0.01 1000 1000];

options=optimset('Display','iter','Jacobian','off',
'MaxFunEvals',maxfuneval,'Maxiter',maxiter,
'TolFun',tolfun,'TolX',tolx,
'LargeScale','on','TypicalX',typical,
'MAxPCGIter',maxPCGiter,'TolPCG',tolPCG);
```

Attached image show (top left) target curve (red) and computed curve(black), others three plots are the lsqnonlin variable in terms of iterations;[image]
Any suggestion how to avoid my error

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output message, your optimization function is starting from a point that is a *local minimum*, meaning all nearby points has a higher error than (or equal to) that point. As typical optimization algorithm will follow gradients downward, the algorithm is effectively stuck in this location.

The simple fix is to try and test other starting points for your minimization algorithm. So something along the lines of changing / randomizing the initial value (e.g. `x0`) for your optimization function. Run the optimization function from random starting points enough times, and you *might* get the global minimum, the settings with the lowest error rate; though this is never guaranteed.

Comment: Sure, this is what it says, but trying other points give the same answer

Comment: Hum, have indeed tried 3 random points, same result. Any suggestion to modify the "options"

Comment: Based on my experience, 3 random points is a really small number, but you're not looking for that. The optimization option seems fine without knowing the specifics of the problem. The only thing I'd want to double check is the `TypicalX` telling the expected magnitude of each variable. Besides this, there is also the option that the system you are trying to optimize is just not able to approximate the target system, and this is the best you can do. Again, without knowing the specifics it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: Problem, it=s that each analysis takes about 4 hours (finite element simulation of 40 years of concrete deterioration). Was not certain that TypicalX is really effective, r if I should pre-condition the variables. There is no doubt (from a physical point of view) that a solution has to exists. Not sure if a different minimization algorithm should be used..

Comment: Is there a variant of lsqnonlin that allows concurrent 2-3 function evaluations in parallel?

Comment: I think the biggest hurdle is that really long evaluation time; 4 hours per evaluation is extremely expensive. I'd look into optimizing the evaluation process before doing anything else. Running tests on a simplified version of your problem is often a good starting point. Reducing `maxfuneval` and `maxiter` will also speed it up, but can give less optimal solutions. Finally, the typical optimization function I use is [`fminsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html), but I simply don't know enough about your problem specifics to provide any guarantees.